# Why don't all elements with the same class have the same padding?

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a webpage and for it I am making a header that includes 4 links/tabs, a logo and a dropdown menu when someone hovers over the 4th tab to display a hidden 5th tab. Everything is working except I can't seem to get the 5th tab (the "cater tab") to have **the same padding as the other four**, even though they all have the same class "tab". Instead, it gives it 0 padding. I was wondering why this is and if there is a way to fix it?

Here's my html:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="tab"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a>About</a></li>
        <li id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" width="260" height="95"/>
        </li>
        <li class="tab"><a>Menu</a></li>
        <ul class="dropdown_container">
            <li class="tab super_tab"><a>Order</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <li class="tab sub_tab"><a>Cater</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my css:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.tab, #logo{
    padding-right: 2.4%;
    padding-left: 2.4%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.dropdown{
    display: table;
}
.dropdown_container{
    display: inline;
}
.sub_tab{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/90udrejh/

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a </ul> tag in there.

Comment: Thank you, though as you know that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: So it's the "Order" item that has incorrect padding, correct? Or is it "Cater" item?

Comment: It is the "Cater" item. Sorry I will edit it to make that more clear.

Comment: Oh sorry, wasn't looking at the padding problem. May be try to add an id to it and assign custom padding?

Comment: I can add custom padding to it, but the thing is I don't want to, and I don't think I should have to. I think it should all be defined based on the fact that in the css everything with a class "tab" should have the same padding. @Blkc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

> `Padding`
>
> Applies to all elements except `table-row-group`, `table-header-group`,
>   `table-footer-group`, `table-row`, `table-column-group` and `table-column`. It
>   also applies to `::first-letter`.

So just change your `display:table` from `.dropdown` to another value that you like and you can't have `<div>` as child of an `<ul>`.

here is a possible snippet

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
.tab,
#logo {
  padding-right: 2.4%;
  padding-left: 2.4%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.dropdown,
.dropdown_container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sub_tab {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab"><a>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a>About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png" width="260" height="95" />
    </li>
    <li class="tab"><a>Menu</a>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown_container">
      <li class="tab super_tab"><a>Order</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <span class="tab sub_tab"><a>Cater</a></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this solves the problem in the jsfiddle example! Though, now that I try to implement it into my original code, I see that the problem also lies somewhere else. Do you think it be fine if I asked a similar question with my original code and see if someone knows the answer based on that?

Comment: yes it is better to ask another question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem originates from `display: table` in the `.dropdown` style. Remove that and the padding returns to normal. However, this may not be the desired method. Usually, inside of a `display: table` divs would be assigned to display as `display: table-column`